# Ranger: cleanup doesn't work

Tags: dired, ranger

I started using ranger and it's awesome, but one thing bothers me: It keeps every visited folder open in a buffer, so it floods my buffer list.

There are two options that seem to be made to solve this problem:

- Ranger Cleanup Eagerly
- Ranger Cleanup On Disable

The first one makes ranger unusable as I cannot open folders anymore in ranger-mode (could be a bug).
The second one sounds exactly like what I am looking for, but has no effect either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could not tag "ranger" because my reputation is too low.

Comment: I don't use ranger, but since it is an extension of dired-mode, perhaps a dired-mode solution would work?  **How do I stop emacs dired mode from opening so many buffers?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839313/how-do-i-stop-emacs-dired-mode-from-opening-so-many-buffers

Comment: Could be related to the problem, but the answers there suggest opening files with `a` or `i`, but these keys have no/a different meaning in ranger. I don't think it's important, but I use Windows 10 and emacs 25.0.50.1.